# In Maven, is it possible to minify files without packaging them into a larger file?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, minify

I’m using Maven 3.3 with Java 6.  I was looking for a plugin that could minify CSS and JS files but not package them into a single file, but rather compress each file and put it in the web application using its same file name and directory structure.  So if I have this file

```
src/main/webapp/css/my.css
```

The resulting minified file would go into

```
target/myproject/css/my.css
```

I’m trying to do this using the Maven minifier plugin using the configuration below but my Javascript files are getting packaged into something called “script.js” and the CSS files are likewise getting packaged into one giant CSS file.  Is there a way to minify each file without compressing them all into a single file?

```
            <profile>
                    <id>minififiles</id>
                    <activation>
                            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
                    </activation>
                    <build>
                            <plugins>
                                    <plugin>
                                            <groupId>com.samaxes.maven</groupId>
                                            <artifactId>minify-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                            <version>1.7.4</version>
                                            <executions>
                                                    <execution>
                                                    <id>default-minify</id>
                                                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                                                    <configuration>
                                                            <cssSourceIncludes>
                                                                    <cssSourceInclude>**/*.css</cssSourceInclude>
                                                            </cssSourceIncludes>
                                                            <jsSourceIncludes>
                                                                    <jsSourceInclude>**/*.js</jsSourceInclude>
                                                            </jsSourceIncludes>
                                                            <jsEngine>CLOSURE</jsEngine>
                                                            <webappTargetDir>${project.build.outputDirectory}</webappTargetDir>
                                                    </configuration>
                                                    <goals>
                                                            <goal>minify</goal>
                                                    </goals>
                                                    </execution>
                                            </executions>
                                    </plugin>
                            </plugins>
                    </build>
            </profile>
```

Comment: Based on the [docs](http://samaxes.github.io/minify-maven-plugin/minify-mojo.html) it should do already so cause `skipMerge` is by default `false` ..?   So i assume you have an other configuration somewhere else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the following options to your configuration:

```
<skipMerge>true</skipMerge>
<nosuffix>true</nosuffix>
```

But be aware that if your are using the default target dirs (which you are not since you are overriding the option `webappTargetDir`), and you set both the options `nosuffix` and `skipMerge` are set to `true`, the plugin execution phase needs to be set to `package`, otherwise the output files will be overridden by the source files during the packaging.

The version of the plugin you are using requires Java 7 and will not work with Java 6.